# Programmatically Altering Gallery Link and image size?

Tags: attachments, gallery

I am in the process of implementing a new template on a site that I manage. part of that migration includes changing the embedded Galleries link setting from file to the attachment page.

I've looked through the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables trying to find where that setting is stored, and read through the function references. I thought that `get_post_gallery()` would get me there but it does not expose that setting either.

this site adds 2-3 posts per day  4-5 days per week for the last 3 years with galleries that need to be changed. Obviously I'd like to knock it out with a script or sql query rather than by hand.

Comment: If you mean the `[gallery]` shortcode, you can check the options [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options) (or [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/#parameters)) and change them in the database. Or use the [`shortcode_atts_gallery` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/) to filter the options dynamically via PHP.

Comment: @SallyCJ Where in the database is the gallery shortcode stored?

Comment: If it's inserted in the post content, then try searching for it in the `post_content` column in `wp_posts`.